# How to execute my query in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate

My table description is

```
desc sensor_log_history;
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| AutoPk      | int(4) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| sensorName  | varchar(20)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| SensorValue | double(65,2)    | NO   |     | 0.00              |                             |
| timest      | timestamp       | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My query is

SELECT   AutoPk,Result1.sensorName, SensorValue,Result1.timest  FROM (SELECT   MAX(timest) AS timest,   sensorName FROM sensor_log_history GROUP BY sensorName) AS Result1 INNER JOIN sensor_log_history  ON Result1.timest = sensor_log_history.timest WHERE Result1.sensorName = sensor_log_history.sensorName;

How to execute this query using hibernate. Hibernate should return a list of objects of type `sensor_log_history`.?

Comment: Do want to know how to convert the above query to HQL? Or do you want to know how to implement the Entity object and other hibernate config?

Comment: I want to know how to convert the above query to hql ?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/            
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/                       
http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-query-example/

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a POJO in your JAVA application and map this table to that POJO using hibernate. Then fire HQL query : "FROM ".

Comment: pojo class i already had. how to execute above mentioned query ? will it work ?